# Making filename remain from path in boost

Tags: c++, file, boost, path

How to delete path from data/lib/blahblah.lua, to make only blahblah.lua remain in a string ??
with Boost library

Comment: What is `data/lib/blahblah.lua`? A string? A `boost::path`? What have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Boost:

```
std::string str = "data/lib/blahblah.lua";
std::string filename(str, str.find_last_of('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross-platform solution, you can use:

```
std::string s = boost::filesystem::path("data/lib/blahblah.lua").filename();
```

If you only want to support POSIX systems, there's a [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/basename.html) function.